# Failed to build wheel with autopy

Tags: python, import, python-wheel, autopy

I was bored recently so I decided to do some programming and follow this tutorial which seemd interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?ev=8gPONnGIPgw&t=244s

During it, he installs the `autopy` module directly from `pycharm`, however when I try it directly  myself from the settings in `pycharm` it doesn't work and I receive an error.

To combat this I decided to follow the instructions on the main site: https://pypi.org/project/autopy/

I tried the first

```
pip install autopy
```

command directly and got a massive error where it first said it failed to build the wheel, and then when it ran the second part `setup.py` it also gave a massive error saying it also failed.

From there I went to the second option:

```
rustup default nightly-2019-10-05
pip install -U setuptools-rust
pip install -U autopy
```

by installing `rustup` and running the other commands but it still fails and gives the "failed to build wheel" and setup.py failed error messages, the exact same ones as before.

Finally I tried the third option:

```
git clone git://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy-rs.git
cd autopy
make
make install
```

by downloading the repository itself and then going into it and using make(that I installed via chocolatey in the `powershell`) and running these commands but it also fails.

I've tried all 3 methods and the internet is yielding minimum results, any help here or resources that may help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
my apologies I thought I added the error, here it is

```
Collecting autopy
  Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: autopy
  Building wheel for autopy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bt_24b82'
       cwd: C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9plfhi_h\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\autopy
  copying autopy\__init__.py -> build\lib\autopy
  running build_ext
  running build_rust
  error: no override and no default toolchain set
  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for autopy
  Running setup.py clean for autopy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9plfhi_h\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97
  Complete output (18 lines):
  running clean
  removing 'build\lib' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.9' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
  running clean_rust
  error: no override and no default toolchain set
  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for autopy
Failed to build autopy
Installing collected packages: autopy
    Running setup.py install for autopy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lgc9_ekn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\autopy'
         cwd: C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9plfhi_h\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\
    Complete output (21 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
    copying autopy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
    running build_ext
    running build_rust
    error: no override and no default toolchain set
    error: can't find Rust compiler

    If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

    To update pip, run:

        pip install --upgrade pip

    and then retry package installation.

    If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9plfhi_h\\autopy_f9372250d2954cabaa93abb9058afa97\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lgc9_ekn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\autopy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please include the whole error

Comment: mb thought i did, edited it in now

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the repository for AutoPy, I've found this issue [here](https://github.com/PyO3/setuptools-rust/issues/59)

Have you tried to use `pip install autopy3` for python 3 and above?
Furthermore, autopy uses rust cargo, you can try to clone the following [repo](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy) and try to build it with Rust (cargo build) on your platform?